# Invalid Authentication key Response From Google

Tags: android, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I am doing a project in android for push notifications using urban Airship however after sending the notification i am getting this error

C2DM push to apid 25cbc337-c3de-4236-b0cc-55806eab 2e8c failed due to invalid auth token

Please guide me to get rid this error

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

It may be an issue with C2DM no longer issuing NEW tokens. You need to update and start using Google Cloud Messenger (GCM) as Google has started deprecating C2DM.

See information here for code migration:
http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/c2dm.html